# "No such file or directory" error

Tags: ruby

I am working through the event_manager intro to ruby lessons, and need to load a file called 
`event_attendees.csv` from my `event_manager.rb`.

I cannot figure out where to put the `event_attendees.csv` file. I know that it needs to go in the root directory but I cannot figure out where that is.

When I look at the `Dir.pwd` for my ruby document, I get:

```
C:/Ruby_Documents/event_manger/event_manager/lib
```

Does it matter that windows uses `\` instead of `/` when I call the doc? This is where I am:

```
puts "EventManager initialized"
contents = File.read "event_attendees.csv"
puts contents
```

Comment: put your code, we will fix it..

Comment: FYI - *[Ruby will convert pathnames](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html) between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename `"/gumby/ruby/test.rb"` will be opened as `"\gumby\ruby\test.rb"`. When specifying a **Windows-style** filename in a Ruby string, **remember to escape** the backslashes:`"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"`*

Comment: Just point to the absolute file, e.g., `File.read("C:/Windows/DirectX.log")`. And yes, the \ escapes characters, so then you'll have to type `"C:\\Windows\\DirectX.log"`. Alternatively, you can change working directory using `Dir.chdir "C:/some_dir"`, then you can use a relative path.

Comment: where your file `event_attendees.csv"` located ? from which directory you are running code ?

Comment: You cannot "look at the `Dir.pwd` for [your] ruby document". `Dir.pwd` tells where you are, not where a file is. To see the location of a file, use `__FILE__`.

Comment: My event_attendees.csv is currently in C:\Ruby_Documents\event_manager  I changed the load line to look like this contents = File.read "C:\\Ruby_Documents\\event_manager\\event_attendees.csv"

Comment: @user3426261 what's the result now ? It should work..

Comment: I am still getting the same error file_name.rb:4:in 'read' " No such file or directory - C:\Ruby_Documents\event_manager\event_attendees.csv (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: Give me the output of `puts File.exist?( "C:\\Ruby_Documents\\event_manager\\event_attendees.csv")`

Comment: It is still saying false

Comment: Yes... because your path or file location is not proper... recheck it..

Comment: Wow, ok I just figured it out, the document was actually titled event_attendees.csv so I needed to look for event_attendees.csv.csv, Thank you so much for the help!  That was driving me crazy for the longest time

Comment: @NickP Heh, lesson learned I suppose; always *uncheck* "Hide extensions for known file types" in Windows ;) It's under `Folder and search options > View`.

Answer (score 0):

according to event_manager instructions you just need one event_manager directory and you need to put your event_attendees.csv in the same directory.